How to connect two APP using 127.0.0.1:12345 in android 14?
The phone system is Android 14
I wrote two APPs
APP A creates a socket listening on 127.0.0.1:12345
APP B want to connect to APP A using 127.0.0.1:12345

When use

new ServerSocket(12345, 50, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1")

create the socket
get java.net.SocketException: socket failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

how to connect B to A using 127.0.0.1:12345

